# How share several vlans with one bond on one interface

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vlan

I search to reproduce this schema in Debian10:

```
         _____eth0                eth1              eth2
        /     /  |                 |                 |
       /     /   |                 |                 |
vlan200  vlan100 |                 |                 |
                 |                 |                 |     
                 _____________________________________
                              |
                         BOND0 + vlan300
```

- When I put 2 vlans in some iface (eth0) with differents IP that is
  ok.
- When I put the bond with vlan, that is ok.
- But when I put 2 vlans in eth0 and I create a bond+vlan in eth0-1-2, only bond run.

I need to put in eth0 several vlans in one eth, and this eth and others run a bond with vlan.

Cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found:

For reasons of simplicity, and to support the use of adapters that can do VLAN hardware acceleration offloading, the bonding interface declares itself as fully hardware offloading capable, it gets the add_vid/kill_vid notifications to gather the necessary information, and it propagates those actions to the slaves. In case of mixed adapter types, hardware accelerated tagged packets that should go through an adapter that is not offloading capable are “un-accelerated” by the bonding driver so the VLAN tag sits in the regular location.

VLAN interfaces must be added on top of a bonding interface only after enslaving at least one slave. The bonding interface has a hardware address of 00:00:00:00:00:00 until the first slave is added. If the VLAN interface is created prior to the first enslavement, it would pick up the all-zeroes hardware address. Once the first slave is attached to the bond, the bond device itself will pick up the slave's hardware address, which is then available for the VLAN device.

Also, be aware that a similar problem can occur if all slaves are released from a bond that still has one or more VLAN interfaces on top of it. When a new slave is added, the bonding interface will obtain its hardware address from the first slave, which might not match the hardware address of the VLAN interfaces (which was ultimately copied from an earlier slave).

From: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bonding